# If I uninstall a steam game (Payday 2), will I keep my progress?

Tags: steam, payday-2

I want to download GTA V, but I don't have enough disk space and the only game I have left to uninstall is Payday 2.

However, I have been playing it frequently, even going on 17 hour marathons to 100%  it, and thus, I am reluctant to uninstall it from my system in case I need to redo everything.

I know the DLCs stay, but I'm talking about the vanilla stuff (Masks, guns, cash, levels, infamy, etcetera).

Comment: yes it will keep your progress as long as you've activated that he syncs with teh steamcloud

Answer (score 7):

## If steam cloud is enabled for Payday 2, all of your save data should be restored when you reinstall Payday 2.

Payday 2 does support the Steam Cloud for backing up save data (in addition to it's own anti-save-corruption measure of having a local backup). If you use the steam cloud, all settings applicable to the stock game (without mods such as Hoxhud, Goonmod, and so forth) should be kept, as well as your inventory, character level, progress towards achievements, and skill tree setups.

#### The following things are NOT saved to the Steam Cloud:

- Achievement Reward (e.g. "Death Wish Skull" Mask) availability. If you have completed an achievement that provides a reward, you will ALWAYS have access to that particular reward. This includes Tabula Rasa for Skill Set #5. Not even Resetting Progress [which does wipe your save] undoes this.
- Access to "Community" items (obtained by following the game on Steam). This has been responsible for quite a few people getting randomly denied access to Nova's Shank or the (old) Hoxton character, among other things.
- Mod-specific options.

Comment: So, do I lose all the Old Hox/ Community group stuff cus: 1. Can I rejoin the group to get back the stuff? And 2. I'M NOT DOING THE GODDAMN HOXTON BREAKOUT HEIST AGAIN. JUST NO.

Comment: For #1: Being in the group is what unlocks it - if you leave the group, then it becomes locked again. For #2: Unless there is some very obscure quirk that hasn't exposed itself, you should only have to get Tabula Rasa once on your steam account to fulfill the achievement requirement for Skill Set #5. (And I had to do Tabula Rasa twice for it to actually unlock, personally, but that's more due to buggy achievement triggers than anything else.)